# jasmine: Adding and reading a query string in the url?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Simply put, in the end, i want to grab the query string from the url and add it to my cookie.

I know how to get the cookie set and am using Vanilla JS for it.

However I want to use Jasmine to test all the wrong cases and not just the happy path.

Anyways, How does one set the url in Jasmine, so that I can pass any query string (like `http://www.blah.com?ref=yayayadaydayday` so that i can use it in my tests using `document.location.search` and take it from there?

I'm guessing whatever it is called when you mock in Jasmine, but if this was rails, i'd add a query string like:

```
  test "can get some results" do
    get :show, :q => shops(:one).name #how do i add this 'q' string in jasmine?!
    refute_nil assigns(:search)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cant mock `window.location`. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792281/mocking-window-location-href-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919370/jasmine-mock-window-object) SO they came up with passing the global context in you function so you can mock it.

Comment: Thanks, those two links look good with many solutions to try.  I read on the jasmine board, you can't do it anyways, because it's just javascript.  Makes me think, isn't there a 'real' test framework that I should use, but that is just the cynic in me i guess. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do something similar, testing some code for a set of tabs which selects a tab if the URL hash is set. I used the history API to manipulate the URL:

```
loadFixtures('tabs-fixtures.html');
window.history.replaceState(null, null, '#three');
```

and the code does indeed read the hash value from the URL.

my test setup uses PhantomJS. I imagine other browsers would work, unless you have an old IE launcher.