# Protractor and Jasmine: How can I test redirects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to write a set of e2e tests using Protractor and Jasmine. I started with this:

```
describe('app login page', function() {
  it('shoudl be redirected to /#/login', function() {
    browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090');
    jasmine.log(window.location.pathname);
    expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual('/#/login');
  });
});
```

But looks like it does not pass in console. I receive the following error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Is there any way to test such redirects?

Comment: Please read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792281/mocking-window-location-href-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getLocationAbsUrl()` to get the current url that is opened in the browser and match its contents with `toMatch()` function that jasmine provides. Here's how -

```
browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090');
expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch('/#/login');
```

Hope it helps.