# Set location.hash and location.href with JSDom

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I am setting up some tests using [JSDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) where I need the `window` and `document` globals and also need to pass a different URL/href for each tests. How do I set the `location.hash` and `location.href` properties?

```
global.document = jsdom({url: 'http://localhost?something=not#test', 'html': ''});
global.window = document.defaultView;
console.log(window.location.href); // returns 'about:blank'
console.log(window.location.hash); // returns no value
```

I have tried assigning values directly to `window.location.hash` with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `location.hash` by inputting string just after `#` in url. Refer to the follow my code.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env({
    url: 'http://localhost?something=not#hash', 'html': '',
    onload: function( window ) {
        console.log(window.location.href); // http://localhost/?something=not#hash
        console.log(window.location.hash); // #hash
    }
});
```

Comment: I realize I didn't quite phrase my question correctly as it was mostly why was href blank. Your answer suggest I need the callback. Is there a way around that? it's very messy doing that in my tests as I need to change the href for each test.

Comment: @Yashua, right! Because page loading is asynchronous, as  [jsdom guide in github](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), It is recommended to use `config.done, config.onload, config.created.`

Comment: I ended up mocking out my own window object - jsdom was way overkill for my tests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792281/mocking-window-location-href-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue too, but was having trouble getting the `jsdom.env(...)` solution to work.  I ended up following the recommendation [here](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#changing-the-url-of-an-existing-jsdom-window-instance), and using jsdom's `changeURL` function.  My test fixture setup looked something like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  // snip...
  jsdom.changeURL(window, 'http://foo/bar')
  // snip...
})
```

Comment: that does not seem to work anymore: `jsdom_1.default.changeURL is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

A lot of these answers are old. Newer `jsdom` versions don't allow you to overwrite things like before. What you're looking for is *probably* the `reconfigure` function.

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const jsdom = new JSDOM();

// ...
jsdom.reconfigure({
  url: 'https://www.test.com/whatever/url/you/want',
});
// ...
```

Documentation for `reconfigure()` can be found [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#reconfiguring-the-jsdom-with-reconfiguresettings).

Check out this [article](https://www.benmvp.com/blog/mocking-window-location-methods-jest-jsdom/) from 2020 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

```
Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'href', {
  writable: true,
  value: 'some url'
});
```

Comment: This answer solved a problem I was having trying to test a component using `HashRouter` from React Router, which was dying with the opaque error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined` when trying to use `createHashHistory()`. The *undefined* was `window.location.hash`, which JSDom doesn't provide, so defining it this way in my test fixed the problem. Hopefully this will help anyone encountering the same issue.