# How to mock "window.location.origin" in jasmine unit test angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to mock `window.location.origin` in my unit test.
I have tried to edit it directly. but it said that the location object is readonly.

I can't find other way.Could you help me?

e,g

```
function login(){
if(window.location.origin) {
    window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
}}
```

How can I test the `login()` function?

Comment: try stubbing window location.. like [mocking window.location.href in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792281/mocking-window-location-href-in-javascript)

Comment: I still don't understand how to handle it ..

Comment: It wuold be easier for everyone if you could provide some code of what you are doing and what is going wrong.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we found a way to mock window object by below code:

```
    windowRedirect(localWindow) {
    const windowObj = localWindow || window;
    windowObj.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
    }
```

UT:

```
    it('Test window', (done: DoneFn)=> {
    const localWindow = {
        location: {
            href: 'currentUrl'
        }
    };
    component.windowRedirect(localWindow);
    expect(localWindow.location.href = 'https://www.google.com');
    done();
   });
```

I think it's still a temporary solution. Please add your comment if you have any other idea.